# Cube doesn't disappear after being beyond the FarClip distance

Tags: javafx

My problem is that after moving my camera away from the cube(-z direction), with setFarClip(-1000), to the position -1010 it won't disappear.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    Box box = new Box(100,100,100);
    Camera cam = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    Group group = new Group();
    group.getChildren().add(box);

    Scene scene = new Scene(group,1920,1080);
    scene.setCamera(cam);

    cam.translateXProperty().set(0);
    cam.translateYProperty().set(0);
    cam.translateZProperty().set(-100);
    cam.setNearClip(1);
    cam.setFarClip(-1000);
    scene.setFill(Color.SILVER);


    System.out.println("CamX: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateX()
            +", CamY: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateY()+", CamZ: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateZ());
    stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event ->{

        switch(event.getCode())
        {
            case W :
                cam.translateZProperty().set(cam.getTranslateZ()+10);
                System.out.println("CamX: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateX()
                        +", CamY: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateY()+", CamZ: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateZ());
            break;


            case A:
                cam.translateXProperty().set(cam.getTranslateX()-10);
                System.out.println("CamX: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateX()
                        +", CamY: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateY()+", CamZ: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateZ());
                break;

            case D:
                cam.translateXProperty().set(cam.getTranslateX()+10);
                System.out.println("CamX: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateX()
                        +", CamY: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateY()+", CamZ: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateZ());
                break;


            case S:
                cam.translateZProperty().set(cam.getTranslateZ()-10);
                System.out.println("CamX: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateX()
                        +", CamY: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateY()+", CamZ: "+scene.getCamera().getTranslateZ());
            break;
        }


    });

    stage.setTitle("Test");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

Instead of printing scence.getCamera().getTranslateX() out, I tried cam.getTranslateX(), which would always give 0.0. So either way it always registers the position as 0.0 and will never be beyond the farclip plane or something entirely else which I didn't grasp or consider. Thank you for every tip.

Comment: When providing an example, please provide reproduction instructions.  For example, you could have written something like: "The app will start with the camera inside the cube, so all you will see is a white screen for the inside of the cube. Hold down the S key.  After a while, the cube will become visible.  Keep holding down the S key while looking at the System.out. Once the value printed reaches a value below -1000, I expect the cube to disappear, but it remains visible even as you continue to hold down the S key and it gets smaller and further away.." -> that would have helped (a lot).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will keep that in mind for future questions. Describing it like you did makes it indeed to a lot easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the sign wrong, instead of:

```
cam.setFarClip(-1000);
```

write:

```
cam.setFarClip(1000);
```

A negative value for farClip would mean to clip behind the camera, which makes no sense.

You may want to review the [coordinate directions for axes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/camera.htm):

> In the JavaFX scene coordinate space, the default camera's projection
> plane is at Z=0 and camera coordinate system is as follows:
>
> - X-axis points to the right
> - Y-axis points down
> - Z-axis points away from the viewer or into the screen.

So a positive Z (which is the measurement for farClip in default camera orientation), is a location into the screen, and a negative Z would be a location behind the screen.